# Why KaTeX is not loaded locally?

Tags: katex

I can't setup KaTeX. It works if I load KaTeX remotely, but it refuses to work locally. Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <link href="katex/katex.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <script defer src="katex/katex.min.js" integrity="sha384-y23I5Q6l+B6vatafAwxRu/0oK/79VlbSz7Q9aiSZUvyWYIYsd+qj+o24G5ZU2zJz" crossorigin="anonymous" integrity="sha384-zB1R0rpPzHqg7Kpt0Aljp8JPLqbXI3bhnPWROx27a9N0Ll6ZP/+DiW/UqRcLbRjq" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script 
    defer
    src="katex/auto-render.min.js" 
    integrity="sha384-kWPLUVMOks5AQFrykwIup5lo0m3iMkkHrD0uJ4H5cjeGihAutqP0yW0J6dpFiVkI" 
    crossorigin="anonymous"
    onload="renderMathInElement(document.body);"
    ></script>



</head>

<body>

    <div id="el"><span>$$2+\frac{1}{x}$$</span></div>

</body>

</html>
```

What can be the reason for not working? If I paste paths of remote files of KaTeX, it works perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

Remove `integrity` and `crossorigin`. And by default the auto-render.min.js is located inside contrib folder, But you did not path it to katex/contrib/auto-render.min.js and you path it to katex/auto-render.min.js. So make sure where the auto-render.min.js is located. if auto-render.min.js is located inside the contrib folder the below code would work.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <link href="katex/katex.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script defer src="katex/katex.min.js"></script>
    <script defer src="katex/contrib/auto-render.min.js"
onload="renderMathInElement(document.body);"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    
        <div id="el"><span>$$2+\frac{1}{x}$$</span></div>
    
    </body>
    
    </html>
```